# Grunt sprite шаблон?

Tags: вёрстка, grunt

Всем привет.

sprite в Gruntfile:

```
sprite:{
      all: {
        src: 'app/img/sprite/*.png',
        dest: 'app/img/sprite.png',
        destCss: 'app/css/less/sprite.less'
      }
    }
```

После запуска создается sprite.png и sprite.less - в котором все миксины для подключения спрайтов(стандартная процедура), но путь к изображению в sprite.less получается таким:
../../img/sprite.png
а мне нужен такой: ../img/sprite.png
то есть мне нужен свой путь, а не относительно файла sprite.less
Может кто сталкивался, как это реализовать?

Тут дело не в Less. Главное как научить его ставить тот путь к sprite.png который мне нужен? Это реализуется думаю через шаблоны, но как его сделать?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Ensighten/grunt-spritesmith#documentation

imgPath String - Optional override for spritesheet path specified in CSS
For example if ../sprite.png is given, then the CSS will have:
background-image: url(../sprite.png);